(LuaLaTeX/Babel) Why does my armenian text go over my .5in margin? is babel setup incorrectly?
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[showframe, margin=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[provide*=*,bidi=basic]{babel} % english is using american english 
\usepackage{microtype}

\setlength\parindent{.1in} 

% Fonts and Languages % 

% Specify languages using \babelprovide
\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}
\babelprovide[import=en-US,main]{english}
\babelprovide[import]{armenian}
\babelprovide[import]{arabic}

% Set fonts for English
\babelfont{rm}{Times New Roman} 
\babelfont{sf}{Aptos}          
\babelfont{tt}{Consolas}        

\babelfont[armenian]{rm}{Times New Roman}
\babelfont[armenian]{sf}{Arial}

\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

A two-inch layer of freshly fallen snow covered the yard. Stacey peeked outside. To most, it would have been a beautiful sight worthy of taking a photo to put on Instagram. For Stacey, it meant something different.

\textsf{A two-inch layer of freshly fallen snow covered the yard. Stacey peeked outside. To most, it would have been a beautiful sight worthy of taking a photo to put on Instagram. For Stacey, it meant something different.
}

\selectlanguage{armenian}
Կարող եմ գրել մի փոքրիկ պատմություն հայերեն: Պատկերացրու մի փոքրիկ գյուղ, որի անունը Ալեքսանդրոպոլ է։ Գյուղը ծովից շատ հեռու է, բայց այնպիսի գեղեցիկ է իր սարերով ու ծաղիկներով, որ ո՛չ մեկը չի ցանկանում թողնել այն։ Գյուղում ապրում են բազմաթիվ բարի մարդիկ, որոնք միշտ պատրաստ են օգնելու։ Ամեն առավոտ նրանք բերում են թարմ հաց ու պանիր իրար, ու միշտ կիսում են իրենց ուրախությունն ու վշտերը։

\textsf{Կարող եմ գրել մի փոքրիկ պատմություն հայերեն: Պատկերացրու մի փոքրիկ գյուղ, որի անունը Ալեքսանդրոպոլ է։ Գյուղը ծովից շատ հեռու է, բայց այնպիսի գեղեցիկ է իր սարերով ու ծաղիկներով, որ ո՛չ մեկը չի ցանկանում թողնել այն։ Գյուղում ապրում են բազմաթիվ բարի մարդիկ, որոնք միշտ պատրաստ են օգնելու։ Ամեն առավոտ նրանք բերում են թարմ հաց ու պանիր իրար, ու միշտ կիսում են իրենց ուրախությունն ու վշտերը։}

\selectlanguage{arabic}

لا يوجد دائمًا إجابة جيدة. بغض النظر عن محاولتك تبرير النتيجة، فإنها لا تبدو منطقية. وبدلاً من إجابة، تبقى مع سؤال واحد. لماذا؟

\end{document}

I am having to write a document that requres me to use english, arabic, and armenian text (this is not the actual text) in TNR. I finished this in Word because I didn't want harp on using LaTeX, but after having done so, I want to know why LaTeX didn't make my Armenian text go inside the margin. I am running Windows with TNR 7.03. I don't know if changing the font changes any result.
Could it be the way I have provide*=* in my preamble? I consulted ChatGPT after having a ahrd time understanding the babel user guide, and it told me that I should load in that option as to have every language use .ini files, which were said to be better than .ldf files since they are more modern and are more flexible. Perhaps it is something else. I would really love if someone could help me out with this issue I am having.

In order to make your code compilable, it's necessary to load the unicode-math package before getting to the \setmathfont instruction.

Please post a screenshot of the output you're getting, so that we may understand better what the problem is you wish to fix.

The problem is not directly related to babel (or to the font), but to the fact there is a single hyphenation point in Ալեքսանդրոպոլ. \showhyphens{Ալեքսանդրոպոլ} shows
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 38--38
[] \TU/TimesNewRoman(1)/m/n/12 Ալեքսանդրո-պոլ

You can added more points with, say:
\babelhyphenation[armenian]{Ալեքս-անդրո-պոլ}


Edit. As per a request, Windows 10 with the latest TeXLive 2024. I had to install Aptos, which is available for free. Times New Roman is 7.00.

+1. :-) For the benefit of future readers of this posting, you may want to add some information about the operating system and fonts you used to compile the test document .

I can't get the Times New Roman and Arial fonts that come with my computer system (MacOS "Sequoia" 15.0.1; MacTeX2024) to generate Armenian text. When I switch to Noto Serif Armenian and Noto Sans Armenian -- two Google fonts that may be downloaded and used free of charge -- I experience no overfull-line problems. Are your copies of Times New Roman and Arial aware of extra languages?
Note that the protrusion of the hyphenation dashes into the right-hand margin is not caused by babel but, rather, by microtype.

\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[showframe, margin=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[provide*=*,bidi=basic]{babel} % english is using american english 
\usepackage{microtype}

\setlength\parindent{0.1in} 

% Fonts and Languages 

\usepackage{unicode-math}

% Set fonts for English
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setsansfont{Arial} % I don't have 'Aptos'
\setmonofont{Consolas}
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}

% Specify languages using \babelprovide
\babelprovide[import=en-US,main]{english}
\babelprovide[import]{armenian}
\babelprovide[import]{arabic}
       
% Set fonts for Armenian and Arabic
\babelfont[armenian]{rm}{Noto Serif Armenian}
\babelfont[armenian]{sf}{Noto Sans Armenian}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Times New Roman}


\begin{document}

A two-inch layer of freshly fallen snow covered the yard. Stacey peeked outside. To most, it would have been a beautiful sight worthy of taking a photo to put on Instagram. For Stacey, it meant something different.

\medskip
\textsf{A two-inch layer of freshly fallen snow covered the yard. Stacey peeked outside. To most, it would have been a beautiful sight worthy of taking a photo to put on Instagram. For Stacey, it meant something different.
}

\bigskip
\selectlanguage{armenian}
Կարող եմ գրել մի փոքրիկ պատմություն հայերեն: Պատկերացրու մի փոքրիկ գյուղ, որի անունը Ալեքսանդրոպոլ է։ Գյուղը ծովից շատ հեռու է, բայց այնպիսի գեղեցիկ է իր սարերով ու ծաղիկներով, որ ո՛չ մեկը չի ցանկանում թողնել այն։ Գյուղում ապրում են բազմաթիվ բարի մարդիկ, որոնք միշտ պատրաստ են օգնելու։ Ամեն առավոտ նրանք բերում են թարմ հաց ու պանիր իրար, ու միշտ կիսում են իրենց ուրախությունն ու վշտերը։

\medskip
\textsf{Կարող եմ գրել մի փոքրիկ պատմություն հայերեն: Պատկերացրու մի փոքրիկ գյուղ, որի անունը Ալեքսանդրոպոլ է։ Գյուղը ծովից շատ հեռու է, բայց այնպիսի գեղեցիկ է իր սարերով ու ծաղիկներով, որ ո՛չ մեկը չի ցանկանում թողնել այն։ Գյուղում ապրում են բազմաթիվ բարի մարդիկ, որոնք միշտ պատրաստ են օգնելու։ Ամեն առավոտ նրանք բերում են թարմ հաց ու պանիր իրար, ու միշտ կիսում են իրենց ուրախությունն ու վշտերը։}


\bigskip
\selectlanguage{arabic}

لا يوجد دائمًا إجابة جيدة. بغض النظر عن محاولتك تبرير النتيجة، فإنها لا تبدو منطقية. وبدلاً من إجابة، تبقى مع سؤال واحد. لماذا؟

\end{document}


Aside: It looks like Noto Sans Armenian -- but not Noto Serif Armenian -- is lacking the glyphs for : and ,. no idea why.

My guess is because : and , do not exist in Armenian punctuation, they have glyphs that look very similar, so probably is an input error by the OP.  Use the Sylfaen font if you have it, for Armenian.

@Mico Windows Times New Roman contains Armenian (at least currently).

@JavierBezos - Thanks for confirming my hunch that various versions of Times New Roman (TNR) can differ markedly in their language/glyph coverage. I suppose the answer I posted isn't as helpful as it might/should be, since I wasn't able to replicate the OP's issue with the somewhat limited TNR and Arial font versions I have on my non-Windows system.
